# SSL Authentication/Authorization is part of handshake or not?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

As per my understanding,
In case of Client Authentication, 
Server request the certificate from the client and then after the certificate verification handshake happens.

I just want to know, what does Server do in the certificate verification:
1) It only verifies that the certificate is valid i.e. the user is the true owner of the certificate.
2) It verifies user is the true owner of the certificate and also check the authentication and authorization.

So 1 or 2 ?

In the simple ways my question is : SSLAuthentication is part of handshake or is something which comes into picture after handshake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the peers if the full validation of the certificates is done before the handshake on the wire is finished or not. Usually server certificate validation is done before the handshake if finished and client certificate validation is done at least partially.

But especially in the case of client certificates it might be that the web application running at the server has additional requirements, for example that the certificate is not only signed by a specific CA but that the subject matches an existing use found in the database and maybe that the fingerprint of the certificate is as stored in the database. In this case the verification is usually only completed after the TLS handshake is finished since only then the web application specific logic is executed.

> ... what does Server do in the certificate verification: 1) It only verifies that the certificate is valid i.e. the user is the true owner of the certificate. 2) It verifies user is the true owner of the certificate and also check the authentication and authorization.

It is checked inside the TLS handshake that the client owns the private key to the public key in the certificate. It is commonly also checked that the certificate is signed by a trusted CA, although there might be scenarios where this check is not done and instead it is checked after the handshake that the certificate has the expected fingerprint. Authorization is usually not checked inside the TLS handshake since the TLS stack has usually no idea yet what kind of resource gets accessed and if the specific user authenticated by the certificate is authorized to access this resource.

Comment: Thank you very much Steffen.

Tomcat has SSLAuthenticator.java class as a valve with authenticate method.

So This will be called after handshake right ?

Comment: @JatinderJindal: I'm not familiar with the innards of Tomcat. But, from a short look at this authenticator it looks like it is executed after the TLS handshake is already done.

Comment: @UllrichSteffen Thanks